# AngularJS: $modal, passing $scope variable to child controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

JS Code,

```
var mod= $modal.open({
    animation: true, 
    templateUrl: $scope.url,
    controller: function($scope, $modalInstance,custObj) {
        alert(custObj); /*************Line 1**************************/
        $scope.save = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function(){
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    },
    resolve : {
        /************Resolving current scope value to retrieve it in Line 1*******/
        custObj: $scope.customer;
    }
});
```

Though I sent `$scope.customer` object via `resolve` property, the modal controller is not getting the value. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `custObj` in the `resolve`-object be a function that returns your `$scope.customer`? Reading the documentation for $routeProvider's resolve I believe that's how it's supposed to be

Comment: @Gustav, Thanks for the point. I thought without a function I can directly pass the values. After changing it to a function everything works fine.

Comment: I'll post as answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `custObj` in the `resolve`-object should be a function returning what you want to inject:

```
resolve: {
  custObj: function(){
        return $scope.customer;
     }
}
```

check [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for $routeProvider resolve

Answer (score 0):

use

```
locals : {
   custObj: $scope.customer;
}
```

instead of resolve.

Comment: Any specific reason why we can choose `locals` instead of `resolve`?